# How to draw jitter plot using gnuplot?

Tags: linux, gnuplot, jitter

I'm trying to plot the data of 100x11 array in plot using gnuplot. I created a .gnu file to generate plot but unable to get jitter plot.

I'm using the below code

```
set terminal pngcairo size 1280,800 enhanced font 'Helvetica,24'
set output "coin_flip.png"

# Title, axis label, range and ticks
set title "Jitter plot of data from coin flip experiment"
set xlabel "Fairness (p)"
set ylabel "# of heads in 10 tosses"
set xrange [-0.1:1.1]
set yrange [-1:11]

# Line styles
set style line 1 lt -1 lw 4 pt 5 lc rgb "red"
set style line 2 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "blue"
set style line 4 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "green"
set style line 5 lt -1 lw 4 pt 13 lc rgb "purple"
set style line 6 lt -1 lw 8 pt 13 lc rgb "black"

# Function definitions and curve fits
set fit logfile 'coin_flip.log'

#Fit
plot "coin_flip.dat" using 1:2 ti "Fairness(p) vs # of Heads" ls 1
```

I'm getting below result

[image]

But I'm trying to get as the below plot

[image]

Below is the graph that I obtain after using

```
set jitter
```

[image]

Can you please help me in plotting?

Comment: .dat file is generated using Matlab

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `set jitter` option on `gnuplot`. The following code:

```
set terminal png
set out "tmp.png" 

set multiplot layout 1,2
unset key

set title "no jitter"
plot x w p

set jitter
set title "jitter"
plot x w p
```

Produces this:

[image: gnuplot jitterg]

You can get fancy on the jitter patterns and other options typing `help jitter` on your `gnuplot` console. Also have a look at these [examples](http://www.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/gnuplot/demo_canvas/jitter.html). Hope it helps!

Comment: When I use set jitter, I'm getting wrong plot i.e., the data is expanded in x axis. I updated the question with the graph that I got after set jitter

Answer (score 0):

```
# coin_flip.gnu
#
# gnuplot instructions to fit and plot the data in coin_flip.dat
#
# Usage:
# gnuplot coin_flip.gnu

# Terminal and output settings
set terminal pngcairo size 1280,800 enhanced font 'Helvetica,24'
set output "coin_flip.png"

# Title, axis label, range and ticks
set title "Jitter plot of data from coin flip experiment"
set xlabel "Fairness (p)"
set ylabel "# of heads in 10 tosses"
set xrange [-0.1:1.1]
set yrange [-1:11]

# borders
set boxwidth 0.1 absolute
set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis
set zzeroaxis

# grid
set style line 12 linecolor rgb '#808080' linetype 0 linewidth 1
set grid back linestyle 12
set grid xtics ytics mxtics

#point size of the data points
set pointsize 15

#puts the key on the top right
set key bottom right

# Function definitions and curve fits
set fit logfile 'coin_flip.log'

set style line 1 lc rgb "red" pt 6
# set style line 2 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "blue"
# set style line 4 lt -1 lw 4 pt 7 lc rgb "green"
# set style line 5 lt -1 lw 4 pt 13 lc rgb "purple"
# set style line 6 lt -1 lw 8 pt 13 lc rgb "black"

#Fit
w=.5
plot "coin_flip.dat" using 1:($2+w*invnorm(rand(0))) ti "P vs Number of Heads" ls 1
```

The above is working fine to generate jitter plot